# Topologies of Matrix Groups & Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Lately I've been delving into the Lorentz and Poincaré groups and their Lie algebras, as well as Lie groups in general. I have a good understanding of the (infinitesimal) generators of boosts and translations, but I am still at a loss regarding the topologies (open sets) of Lie groups of matrix spaces and of general pseudo-Euclidean spaces.

Given a vector norm $\lVert \cdot\rVert:V\to\mathbb R$, does the operator norm of a matrix

$$\lVert A\rVert_{op}=\sup{\left\lbrace\lVert A x\rVert : \lVert x\rVert \leq 1\right\rbrace}$$

induce a useful or "standard" topology on the space $\mathbb{R}_{m \times n}$ of $m\times n$ matrices? Also, given a vector space isomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^{m\cdot n}\to \mathbb{R}_{m\times n}$, does the final topology

$$\mathcal{T}=\left\lbrace U \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{m\times n} : f^{-1}(U) \text{ open}\right\rbrace$$

define another useful topology? Furthermore, in a pseudo-Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$, does a quadratic form $q:\mathbb{R}^{p,q}\to \mathbb{R}$ (or its induced symmetric bilinear form) induce any kind of topology?

In a broader sense, how does one go about showing that $\mathrm{O}(p,q)$, $\mathrm{SO}(p,q)$, $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, etc. are Lie groups i.e. differentiable manifolds?

Comment: All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space generate the same topology, and so the operator norm on the space of matrices will generate the same topology as, for example, the Euclidean norm you would get by treating an $n \times m$ matrix as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{nm}$.

Comment: I'm not aware of this property on the equivalence of topologies of norms. Does this proposition have a name, or is there a proof somewhere?

Comment: It's a standard theorem in functional analysis. If you search around for "norm" and "finite dimensional" I'm sure it'll show up.